# How to configure Symfony with Netbeans

Tags: symfony, netbeans, configuration

Now that Symfony have no longer a zip file to download. How can we create a symfony projet in Netbeans ? I have searched a lot and everything relies on the zip file. But the zip file is no longer the standard installation for Symfony

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download the latest version of the project as said here http://symfony.com/download, then zip the forder in with the files have been put, and finally add the zip to Netbeans as previous, with older versions.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could always make your own .zip file but I'm not sure why this is a problem. I just use [one of the existing installation methods](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) to get a working-copy going and then in NetBeans create a "PHP Application with Existing Sources" project and point it to the working copy.